# bootstrap 4 collapse not working with jquery minified version

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to add a jquery FadeOut effect to a badge but the problem is the (effect or the function) needs 
the minified version (the full one) so I replaced the slim CDN with the full version (3.5.0) CDN and then the 
bootstrap 4 ( collapse class ) stopped working.

**code:- include**

```
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap CDN Font-awesome -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->
```

**collapse code and fadeOut:-**

```
<script>
    function badgefade(){
        // document.getElementById("").
        $("#notificationsBadge").fadeOut("slow");
    }
</script>

<div class="collapse" id="'.$item['companyexported'].'"> ..... </div> ---- Collapse Not Working

<a class="nav-link" href="#" id="notificationsdrop" onclick="badgefade()" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

*2*:- I remember I have another issue in (Onclick) attribute the function is only triggered once what I'm trying to do is replace font awesome icon onclick

[image: screenshot]

**code->**

```
<script>
function arrow(){
    if (document.getElementById("arrow").className = "fa fa-arrow-down") {
        document.getElementById("arrow").className = "fa fa-arrow-up";
} else {
    document.getElementById("arrow").className = "fa fa-arrow-down";
}
}
</script>

<h3><a class="btn btn-success billbtn" onclick="arrow()" data-toggle="collapse" style="width: 280px !important;"href="#'.$item['companyexported'].'" aria-expanded="false" style="direction:RTL;"aria-controls="contentId"><i id="arrow" class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="float:left" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="badge badge-light">'.$item['accountid'].'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;فاتورة ('.$item['companyexported'].')</a></h3>
```

Comment: You havent imported popper.js which is mendatory for bootstrap. Go this URL and add dependencies, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/.

Comment: @noobprogrammer I put it before jquery and nothing happens console ``:Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at Object.jQueryDetection (util.js:176)
    at util.js:192
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
profile.php:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at openNav (profile.php:36)
    at HTMLElement.onclick (VM5304 profile.php:89)``

Comment: @Rusty I know I just deleted I thought it well work however  I added it again and nothing happens

Comment: You need to preventDefault() the anchor tag('a'). You can't bind any function to it without preventing its default action.

Comment: @Pranaykumar I'm sorry please mind me are you talking about the arrow or the collapse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing is popper.min.js as correctly pointed out by **Rusty**

Include the below script in the same order as mentioned:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am glad it helped. :) if you find this helpful please mark is as answer so that people can find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery 3.5.1 has been released.It fixes the issue with collapse in bootstrap 4.4.1
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30553